# Are Euro coins copyrighted?

Tags: eur-euro

So I want to make a game, where you can find Euro coins, and I want them to be exactly the same as the real ones. Is this ok, or am I violating some copyrights?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a PF question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the ECB (European Central Bank) website, I followed a rabbit-warren of links and eventually arrived at [what I think is the relevant instrument](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:52011XC0210(02)), a "Communication from the Commission on copyright protection of the common face design of the euro coins". From which:

> 1. Holder of the copyright
>
> The copyright on the design of the common face of the euro coins
>   belongs to the European Union represented by the Commission. The
>   European Commission has assigned to each Member State that has adopted
>   the euro all the Union's rights as regards the territory of such
>   Member State. The Commission will assign the copyright to the other
>   Member States once they adopt the euro.
>
> 2. Reproduction regime
>
> The following common reproduction regime will be applied by the
>   Commission and by the participating Member States, as defined in
>   Regulation (EC) No 974/98, as regards their territory. Reproduction of
>   all or part of the common face design of the euro coins is
>   **authorised without recourse to a specific procedure** in the following cases:
>
> - for photographs, drawings, paintings, films, images, and generally reproductions in flat format (without relief) provided they are in
>     faithful likeness and are used in ways which do not damage or detract
>     from the image of the euro,

So although the images are copyright, you can go ahead and use them, it seems to say to me.

---

HOWEVER this only covers the *common* faces of the coins - as you probably know, for all euro coins one side is a common pan-European design, while the other varies depending on the issuing member state. I haven't looked into arrangements for those sides - presumably copyright resides with the issuing state, and at a guess they will have a similar provision to the above.

Finally, a note that although the above linked page says 'no longer in force', the only effect of the successor documents is to expand the list of member state banks; the copyright provision is unchanged.